# .gitIgnore for files with two file types

Tags: git

I need to create a gitIgnore entry to ignore files from Allen-Bradley Studio 5000 which creates backup files as I work with endings similar to 
`ProjectName.BAK012.acd` where the number after "BAK" changes constantly.
Unfortunately, the files I don't want to ignore follow the format 
`ProjectName.acd`

How do I add a rule to gitIgnore for the ".BAK###.acd" files without including the standard ".acd" files?

Answer (score 1):

`*.BAK*` manages to ignore the files I want.